# Consider renaming the application

Tags: discussion, feature-request, ios-app

Right now, in iOS, the app label shows as "Stack Exc..."

While we all know what it means, it's not really nice.
So how about calling it instead "StckExchg" :)

Or some other form, that will still convey "Stack Exchange", but not with all letters, or something alike...

Comment: Eww, I hate that even more. However it is a fair point. Maybe just "Stack" for the short form. Or SE

Comment: StackEx? StackExch?

Comment: `Exch` seems to be a common abbreviation for Exchange, so StackExch might be enough, although I'd prefer something to keep the space

Comment: Yeah I'd go with "Stack".

Comment: "Stack" is pretty bad, IMO. I know it's gaining traction as a short form for the company's name, but it's still like nails on chalkboard to me. That said, I could definitely get on board with "SE".

Comment: I can work with that too.

Comment: Maybe just abbreviate the first word... S. Exchange? .. on second thought, SE does seem more applicable as Anna suggests. StckExchg could be the Stock Exchange (or some other similar naming convention) which probably wouldn't work very well.

Comment: @Anna for me its always "the Stack".